# HIVE ql/ sub queries getting confused on join

Tags: sql, hive

group by 2 paramters

I am trying write this query in HIVEQL, i know for a fact we need to use GROUP by bcity and bstate. I am just not sure where i am going wrong, this gives me an error after i add `group by a.bcity,a.bstate` it gives me an error that id not found as attribute. But before the addtion it ran fine and produced this:

[image]

```
SELECT a.id, a.bcity, a.bstate,b.combo FROM master a 
JOIN (SELECT id, SUM(doubles) + SUM(triples) as combo FROM batting
GROUP by id) b JOIN 
WHERE a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.bcity,a.bstate
Order by combo DESC
limit 5;
```

Look below foe schema

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS batting
    (id STRING, year INT, team STRING,
    league STRING, games INT, ab INT, runs INT, hits INT, doubles INT, triples INT, 
    homeruns INT, rbi INT, sb INT, cs INT, walks INT, strikeouts INT, ibb INT, 
    hbp INT, sh INT, sf INT, gidp INT) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/home/hduser/hivetest/batting';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS master
    (id STRING, byear INT, bmonth INT, bday INT, bcountry STRING, bstate STRING, 
    bcity STRING, dyear INT, dmonth INT, dday INT, dcountry STRING, dstate STRING, 
    dcity STRING, fname STRING, lname STRING, name STRING, weight INT, height INT, 
    bats STRING, throws STRING, debut STRING, finalgame STRING, retro STRING, 
    bbref STRING) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION '/home/hduser/hivetest/master';
```

Comment: You might try to explain what you want the query to do.  Personally, I can think of many queries in HiveQL that do not need to be grouped by city and state, so some guidance on goals -- through sample data and desired results -- is helpful.

Comment: Trying to Sum up the number of doubles and triples for each
birthCity/birthState combination. Output the top 5
birthCity/birthState combinations that produced the players who had the most doubles and triples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i have said, NOT by id and but by city and state.

this works

```
SELECT a.bcity, a.bstate, SUM(b.combo) as total
 FROM master a JOIN
       (SELECT id, SUM(doubles) + SUM(triples) as combo
  FROM batting 
  GROUP by id
 ) b 
 ON a.id = b.id
GROUP by a.bcity,a.bstate
ORDER BY total DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

As I interpret the question, you want the information for 5 players, not 5 cities.  You can sort-of follow the structure you laid out, but by using `LIMIT` in the *subquery*, not the *outer query*:

```
SELECT m.bcity, m.bstate, b.combo
FROM master m JOIN
     (SELECT id, SUM(doubles) + SUM(triples) as combo
      FROM batting b
      GROUP by id
      ORDER BY combo DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) b 
     ON m.id = b.id
ORDER BY combo DESC;
```

Comment: no definetly need city, state group by clause. Output the TOP 5 
birthCity/birthState combinations that produced the PLAYERS  who had 
the most  doubles and triples.

Comment: also the alias a is not used any where, but also b is used twice in the subquery and outside

Comment: SELECT m.bcity, m.bstate, SUM(b.combo)
FROM master m JOIN
     (SELECT id, SUM(doubles) + SUM(triples) as combo
      FROM batting b
      GROUP by id
      ORDER BY combo DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) b 
     ON m.id = b.id
GROUP by m.bcity,m.bstate
ORDER BY combo DESC;

Comment: this might be what i am looking for ^ but syntactically it might be off